# Floating block links broken in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #nav {
                float: left;
                width: 10em;
            }

            #nav ul {
                list-style: none;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0 20px;
            }

            #nav li {
                margin-top: 9pt;
                position: relative;
            }

            #nav a {
                border: solid 1px black;
                display: block;
                width: 10em;
                padding: 3px 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container1">
        <div id="container2">
            <div id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href=".">Welcome</a></li>
                    <li><a href="news">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="faq">FAQ</a></li>
                            <li><a href="charity">Charity</a></li>
                            <li><a href="committee">Committee</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
           <div id="section">If this p is here, the block links no longer work.<br><br><br></div>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In IE8 the text in #section prevents the whitespace in a block link from being a link. While there is text to the right, the whitespace in the links breaks. When the #section div ends, the links work fine and the whole thing is a link rather than just the text.

How would I make the whole a element a link all the time, rather than just the text when the #section div interfers? I've tried z-order to no avail.

Comment: I can't work out what you are asking. Could you link to a web-page with the failing behavior?  Also your code won't validate - there are 4 `div` start tags and 5 `div` end tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add a background color to #nav

Comment: How did that solve the problem? Did you just get to see what was going on with the elements' positioning?

Comment: Changing the background color triggered the hasLayout() method within IE which wasn't previously triggered. If this actually fixed it, please mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Either remove the `width: 10em;` in your `#nav` style, or change it to `width: 210px;`.

Answer (score 0):

After trying out your code, I've found that the links work just fine for me with your code as it's posted above; I only ran your problem when the `#section` div was relatively positioned.  In that case, `#section` gets placed higher than the links and actually covers them.  That's why it looks as if the link simply doesn't work.  Put a background color on `#section` and you'll see what I mean.

You actually can fix it using the z-index property.  Set it to a value of about 10 for `#nav li` and use any number higher than that for `#section`, and **as long as both of those elements are relatively positioned**, you should see the links on top of the `#section` div.  It should look something like this:

`#nav li { margin-top: 9pt;
position: relative;
z-index: 10;
}`

`#section {
position: relative;
z-index: 20;
}`

For more on positioning, there's a really good article at CSS-Tricks that you might want to read: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Comment: `z-index` won't solve the issue (ICR mentions that he had tried it to no avail... and I tried it as well). Replace his *section* `DIV` with `<div id="section">If this p is here, the block links no longer work.<br>If this p is here, the block links no longer work.</div>` and try to click the *Welcome* box where the text in the *section* `DIV` overlaps the *Welcome* box. It selects text from the *section* `DIV` instead of firing on the *Welcome* link.

Comment: Right. z-index only works when both elements have been positioned.  a `position:relative` needs to be added to `#section` to make a difference.